# When do you get Mouse.getstate().X or Y as negative?

Tags: xna, input, mouse

I am creating a game in which I use a function:

```
int x()
        {
            int px = 100;
            int pxend = 128;
            int xx = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            {
                l = Mouse.GetState().X;
                if (l> px && l < pxend)
                {
                    xx = px;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    px += 128;
                    pxend += 128;
                }
            }
            return xx;
        }
```

and

```
int y()
        {
            int px = 100;
            int pxend = 128;
            int xx = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                l = Mouse.GetState().X;
                if (l > px && l < pxend)
                {
                    xx = px;
                    break;
                }
                else
                { px += 128;
                pxend += 128;
                }
            }
            return xx;

        }
```

But when I debug I get value a `l` as negative even though the debug is initiate after a click on the `GameWindow` screen. Sometimes it works fine sometime does not. I dont know why does it give me negative value. And when I used them with my `Rectangle` i get `Rectangle.X and Rectangle.Y` as `0`.

Comment: You might want to simplify your code and ensure the `for` loops are not causing this behavior. You can just use `GetState()` once outside the `for` loop, since when retrieving it again inside the loop it won't change.

Comment: nope nothing happens...the result is the same as before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per this MSDN article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.input.mousestate.x.aspx, The mouse location is based on the top left of the game window.  So, if the mouse escapes the window, the mouse location will be negative.  Also, some windows counts a pixel or two to the left of the screen, so this is not an uncommon behavior.

If you are getting strange values in general, make sure you turned on the mouse in the Game's Property list, and that you are retrieving the values right.  In general, you don't want to use the value of Mouse.GetState() straight.